# Как изменить bool параметр настроек шейдера? (на примере чекбокса TwoSided)

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image]

Для реализации  задачи мне нужно получить доступ к это параметру,  включать его при надобности, и выключать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках шейдера нету метода SetBool(). Вместо булевых значений у шейдерах используются инты, соответственно нужно воспользоватся методом SetInt();

Так что в твоем случае должно быть что-то вроде:

```
material.SetInt( "_TwoSided", 1 ); //включен
material.SetInt( "_TwoSided", 0 ); //выключен
```

но точное название '_TwoSided' нужно подсмотреть внутри шейдера

Comment: по правде сказать и тип тоже надо в исходниках смотреть, т.к. чекбокс может быть и для SetFloat

Answer (score -1):

Есть метод у материала,  SetFloat(). Передаём туда первый параметр "_Cull",  второй параметр 0f(включить) 2f(выключить). 
Пример:
material.SetFloat("_Cull", 0f);